# Fleetctl job already exists

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

Having issue with deploying a docker container to CoreOS. Notice the following

```
~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl status example.service                                    
Job example.service does not exist.

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl submit example.service                                    
Failed creating job example.service: job already exists

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl destroy example.service                                   
Destroyed Job example.service

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl submit example.service                                    

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl start example.service                                     
Failed creating job example.service: job already exists

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl destroy example.service                                   
Destroyed Job example.service

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl submit example.service                                    

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl start example.service                                     
Failed creating job example.service: job already exists

~CED_HOME/ » fleetctl status example.service 
Job cedregistry.service does not exist.
```

The service(container) is not there, however doing a submit says it's there, destroy it, great now we can do a submit, then a start, but same error, go through the destroy submit again, but same issue.

Anyone have a idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

turns out, I was running a old version of fleetctl, upgraded to the latest version of github and it's working perfectly.